# Upload a picture in signup with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase.auth to sign up users on my website. 
In order to get more informations from them, I also create a Firestore Document that stores more informations. Here is my code:

HTML

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center h-md-100vh">
                  <div class="col-10 my-5 my-md-0">
                     <h2 class="h4 font-weight-bold">Signup To Become A Player</h2>
                     <form id="player-login-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="text" id="player-signup-firstname" name="player_signup[firstname]" required="required" placeholder="What&#039;s your firstname?" class="form-control">
                           <div class="invalid-feedback mt-0"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="text" id="player-signup-lastname" name="player_signup[lastname]" required="required" placeholder="What&#039;s your lastname" class="form-control">
                           <div class="invalid-feedback mt-0"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="email" id="player-login-email" name="player_signup[email]" required="required" placeholder="What&#039;s your email?" class="form-control">
                           <div class="invalid-feedback mt-0"></div>
                           <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                           <input type="password" id="player-login-password" name="player_signup[password]" required="required" placeholder="Set a password" class="form-control">
                           <div class="invalid-feedback mt-0"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="cameraInput">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="player-signup-button">Create account</button>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

And JS

```js
// The sign up variables and constants
    const signUpBtn = document.querySelector('#player-signup-button');

    // Sign up function 
    signUpBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid the page to refresh when we click signup
        // get user info from the id of the input
        const loginForm = document.querySelector('#player-login-form');
        const firstname = loginForm['player-signup-firstname'].value;
        const lastname = loginForm['player-signup-lastname'].value;
        const email = loginForm['player-login-email'].value;
        const password = loginForm['player-login-password'].value;
        // Upload picture part
        var refname = 'photos/' + firstname + lastname;
        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(refname);
        let fileUpload = document.getElementById("cameraInput")
        fileUpload.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
            console.log("Is code going here?");
            let firstFile = evt.target.files[0] // upload the first file only
            let uploadTask = storageRef.put(firstFile).then(function(fileSnapshot) {
                firebase.firestore().collection('players').add({
                    firstname: firstname,
                    lastname: lastname,
                    email: email,
                    profilepic: fileSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
                });
            })
        });
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            M.toast({html:error.message});
        }).then( cred => {
            loginForm.reset();
        });

    });
```

**My question: ** I have issues for the image uploading part. It looks like the code inside fileUpload.addEventListener is not read by the interpreter.

Do you have any ideas where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this callback registration outside the click handler:

```
document.getElementById("cameraInput").addEventListener('change', function(evt) {...});
```

Right now your code says "after the user submits the form, start listening for them to browse for a picture" when what you really want is "when the page loads, start listening for the user to browse for a picture. Afterwards, when they submit the form read the selected picture file and send it to the server."

Comment: I understand. The problem is, I need these informations for the submit form, right?

Comment: Because some informations that I store in Firestore are from the submit form, and one information is from this listener. You can see for example that the variable refname needs both listeners

Comment: The 'change' event happens when the user clicks the "browse" button and selects a file. That will always happen before the user clicks your submit button. You can either use the 'change' event to do something with the file when it's selected or use `let photo = document.getElementById("cameraInput").files[0];` to grab the selected file in your submit button handler, where you'll push the file to Firestore.

The object returned from `.files[0]` will be a `File`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: @Abilys38 You bet!